# Запрет скроллинга страницы без потери управляемости скроллбара

Tags: javascript

Товарсчи, есть ли возможности в js для того чтобы запретить прокрутку всей страницы, но при этом скроллбар не исчезал, а наоборот продолжал работать, но для другого элемента в документе. В том, элементе нужно будет отлавливать событие onscroll.

Answer (score 0):

думаю тебе необходимо сделать html{ overflow: hidden; }, а на другом элементе документа сделай overflow: auto;

Comment: это не работает, так как overflow:hidden  прячет полосу прокрутки, а нужно, чтобы имнно эта полоса скролила другой элмент дока

Comment: Тобишь скролл всего сайт не скроллил весь сайт, а только маленьки (к прмиеру) блок?
это делается только установкой таких значений в css, все SPA так делают иначе придется костылить и делать свою полосу прокрутки назначать позицию через него...)

Comment: если тебе помог мой ответ, отметь его как "Ответ")

Comment: не подскажешь какие свойства за это отвечают?

Comment: свойства чего? ты про js?